# How would shell-maille fare against oceanic predators?

Tags: armors, mermaid

Imagine merpeople(your typical half-fish bodied mermaid sort) have managed to construct a form of maille armour out of shells and gold in a similar manner to scalemaille. Shells because they're hard and abundant enough to make up the scales and can easily be replaced, and gold because it's a malleable metal that would serve the purposes of creating links to hold all of the shells together and doesn't corrode underwater. They're not wholely limited to the water and can go on land for as long as they don't dehydrate with all the awkwardness that would entail, which is where they use forges and such to shape the gold. The exact kind of shells they'd use would vary, but for the most scale-like look we'll go with clam shells for the purposes of this question.

I am aware of gold being rather heavy, and as such I've sort of handwaved their ability to wear these and not sink by way of a warrior caste that are strong enough to swim through the water despite being weighed down by the gold(if this is not necessary and they wouldn't sink too much then yay but I'm still keeping the warriors).

What I'm interested in knowing is: How well will this armour fare against attacks from your typical oceanic predators like sharks, leopard seals, orca, and the ocasional large cephalopod?

Comment: If your armor contains enough gold that the weight of it bothers you, then you will have bigger problems than sea predators!

Comment: Indeed. If we take the average hauberk weight of 10kg and multiply it by 2.418(density of gold vs iron, 19.03 grams per cubic cm vs 7.87 grams per cubic cm, 19.03/7.87=2.418etc) you'll get a hauberk of gold weighing 24.18kg, which is kinda really heavy if you're planning to swim with it. Even wearing it on land is going to be taxing. You're adding shells as well, so tack on a few extra kilos too, and honestly you might just be better off with only the gold maille(despite gold's softness). I suggest simply using a strong kind of string for your shell armour if you want to stick with the shells.

Comment: Lol I suggested scale-maille to someone a little while ago. I'm glad someone else has the same idea :)

Comment: They have shell-maille! Release the whelks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR - The armour would not fare well...

I don't have figures on bite force etc. to hand, although I suspect the numbers would be but a Google away.  However I have seen enough documentaries to know that the largest shark species are capable of biting seals clean in two.  I strongly suspect even the best modern stainless steel butcher's mail would be largely useless against that kind pressure.  Even without penetration the hapless merfolk would be crushed.

Orcas may bring them to the surface and fling them about like rag dolls, again making armour redundant.  And they hunt in packs.  And display learning and problem solving levels of intelligence.

Leopard seals do not seem to frequently display aggression toward divers, so it is hard to say what their reaction would be, but again, if it got to the point one got a good enough bite that the victim was relying on their armour, the seal's strength and weight is going to put it at a distinct advantage.

I know next to nothing about the actual capabilities of giant squid and octopus, so I cannot offer any opinion there.

To think about a similar but possibly more familiar set of circumstances, I would expect armour made of plates of bone to be similarly effective against an attack by a bear or tiger.

Against threats like these I think detection, avoidance, speed and manoeuvrability are the best defences.

Comment: Speed = defense basically... got it!